# How to calculate binary logarithm (log2) for double in Java?

Tags: java, math

How to calculate binary logarithm (log2) for double in Java?
There is no default method.

Comment: static double log2(double value) {
        return Math.log(value) / Math.log(2);
    }

Comment: Yes, I wanted answered myself, so that answer was there and it be able searches from search-system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base

The logarithm log<sub>b</sub> x can be computed from the logarithms of x and b with respect to an arbitrary base k using the following formula:

log<sub>b</sub> x = log<sub>k</sub> x / log<sub>k</sub> b

For the specific case asked for in the question, take b = 2 and k = 10.

log<sub>2</sub> x = log<sub>10</sub> x / log<sub>10</sub> 2

But this is mathematics, not programming.